# Creating reactive form with array of objects value in Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms

I need to create form in Angular.

```
SampleJson={
[{type:'text',name:'firstname', value:'Test'},
{type:'text',name:'lastname', value:'Test'},
{type:'mail',name:'email', value:'Test'}],[{type:'text',name:'firstname', value:'Test'},
{type:'text',name:'lastname', value:'Test'},
{type:'mail',name:'email', value:'Test'}]}  

  ngOninit(){
    this.form=this.fb.group({
    emp:this.fb.array({})
    });
this.buildForm();
}

buildForm(){
const controls = sampleJson.map(option => new FormControl(option.value));
    const formArray = new FormArray(controls);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div  *ngFor="let field of sampleJson">
<div *ngFor="let control of field">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="control.type">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
                  <input type="text" [formControlName]="control.name">
            </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
</div>
</div`
```

Kindly let me know how any have idea. I need to use reactive form method. I have tried lot of different approaches.

Comment: What's your problem with that?

Comment: @Shifenis, it is not working

Comment: Please update the question with more information about your error(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SampleJson.forEach(item=> {
    this.formGroup.addControl(
        item.name, // control name
        new FormControl("",)
    );
});
```

Use this approach of adding Control from Array Object.